# Has there been a measurement of a stalling force for myosin molecular motors?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, cytoskeleton

For processive molecular motors like kinesin, [in vitro assays](https://elifesciences.org/articles/44146) have allowed to measure directly a stalling force beyond which they do not progress anymore or detach.

As far as I know, the literature has only very indirect ways of evaluating what a stall force may be for myosin molecular motors, is this true? If so, is it because of the nonprocessivity of most myosin motors, or are there other experimental obstacles to this measurement?